# How do you restart a juju service?

Tags: services, juju

I manually changed a config option in a juju service (alice-irc), now I want to restart it, how do I do so?  I rebooted the instance figuring that would do it but no luck. I then tried running the start script that is in `/var/lib/juju/units/alice-irc-0/charm/hooks` and it failed with a bunch of errors.  So what's the right solution here?

EDIT: The start script did actually start the service, but dumped errors out due to the juju-log calls.  I'd still like to know what the "right" solution is here.

Comment: The Service is running on its own instance as a Service. Can't you ssh into the instance and restart the service manually? A Reboot should do the this, too. Maybe be your config changes are the problem? Please post the error messages.

Comment: `sudo service <servicename> restart` restarts the mentioned service...

Comment: That is only true for services with upstart jobs, it is not universal.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if this was a Juju config option for the charm, I think the charm should restart it automatically. If not, it probably should be added to the config (but the README says "This charm doesn't offer any configuration as Alice doesn't have any command line configuration tools, everything is done through the browser.")